# como solucionar el error? ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]CONTEXTO
andamos creando un procedimiento en Mysql y al momento crear el procedimiento no presento problema alguno sin embargo cuando cuando se trata de llenar el procedimiento almacenado me marca que "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" a que se deberá? dejo mi código de mysql y captura de mis tablas
lo que se quieres es realizar un punto de una actividad que es el siguiente:
Crea un procedimiento almacenado (PA) para ingresar registros en cliente, considerando la edad del cliente; si un cliente es menor a 15 años, no podrá registrarse, debido a que los clientes de la agencia de viajes son mayores a 14 años. Por tal motivo, se deberá enviar un mensaje indicando lo anterior, de lo contrario, se podrá ingresar el cliente y se enviará un mensaje: Cliente registrado. Este PA, deberá incluir una función para el cálculo de la edad. Además, se deberá considerar que dentro de la tabla Cliente, no podrán haber registros repetidos.

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvizn.jpg)

codigo demysql

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  delimiter //
MariaDB [(none)]> use viajes_ia//
Database changed
MariaDB [viajes_ia]> Create function CalcularEdadIA(FN date)
    -> returns int(2)
    -> begin
    -> declare Edad int(2);
    -> set Edad=timestampdiff(year, FN, curdate());
    -> return Edad;
    -> end//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.017 sec)



MariaDB [viajes_ia]> create procedure InsertClientesIA(N varchar(35), P varchar(35), M varchar(35), FN date,Cal varchar(50),Num int(5),CodP int(10))
    -> comment 'Porfavor ingresa los datos de los clientes'
    -> begin
    -> declare Edad int(2);
    -> set Edad=CalcularEdadIA(FN);
    -> if not exists (select * from cliente_ia where Nombre=N and AP=P and AM=M and FechaN=FN) then
    -> if(Edad>15) then
    -> insert cliente_ia values(NULL,N,P,M,FN,Cal,Num,CodP);
    -> select CONCAT('El cliente', N ,'se ha registrado correctamente en la base de datos') as Mensaje;
    -> else
    -> select CONCAT('La edad de ', N , 'no es permitido') as Mensaje;
    -> end if;
    -> else
    -> select CONCAT('Este cliente ', N, 'ya esta registrado') as Mensaje;
    -> end if;
    -> end //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.018 sec)

MariaDB [viajes_ia]> call InsertClientesIA ('Felipe','Hernandez','Cruz','2000-10-04',80796, 32,'San Pedro')//
**ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. No sabemos la estructura de la tabla cliente_ia. Por favor, ve a [edit] y añádela

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No esribas nunca inserts implícitos, conviene indicar siempre cada columna explícitamente, así evitarás este tipo de errores o que el código falle si alguna tabla evoluciona.

Comment: Como se pueda apreciar, tu tabla tiene `9` columnas, pero tú estás pasando `8` valores: `values(NULL,N,P,M,FN,Cal,Num,CodP)` **ese** es el problema de escribir inserts implícitos, aparte de que te puedes equivocar en el orden de los valores. Escribe la consulta así: `INSERT INTO laTabla (col1, col2, colN) VALUES (val1, val2, valN)`

Comment: Ese error se debe a que en tu tabla hay un valor que excede de lo que le has puesto por ejemplo si tienes un dato varchar(35) No puedes meter un valor de 36 letras te da ese error, otra cosa que también puede ser es porque te has equivocado al meter un campo por ejemplo un dato INT el cual le pones al insertar una palabra o letra y la ultima cosa que puede ser es que te falte añadir una columna que no te has dado cuenta a la hora de insertar

Comment: Omitiste la columna Edad